# explorer don't get cookie, but chrome do

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, cookies

i am korean. so i don't speak english well.

first,

i have a four page, named A.php, B.php, cookie.php, view.php

i want get a cookie in page, chrome is done, but explorer is do not..^^:;

plz give me a hint, you see my code.

### A.php - this page set a cookie, exclude call.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var m3_u = "http://[myip]/cookie.php?";
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("'></scr"+"ipt>");
```

### B.php - this page get a cookie, exclude call.

```
     <script type='text/javascript'>
   var m3_u = "http://[myip]/view.php?";
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("'></scr"+"ipt>");
 </script>
```

---

### cookie.php - this page set a cookie

```
<?
    setcookie('sheep','mehehe~',time()+100,"/");
?>
```

---

### view.php - this page set a cookie

```
<?
    if(isset($_COOKIE['sheep'])
       echo $_COOKIE['sheep'];

?>
```

---

- A,B is same server, cookie.php,view.php is same server
  i want get a cookie in B.php and use $_COOKIE['sheep'] value.
  chrome is done, explore do not..; why? give me a hint plz..

Comment: use `vardump()` on `$_COOKIE['sheep']` to see if the value you are expecting appears. My guess is on explorer you didn't run `cookie.php`?

Comment: welcome to browser world, explorer doesn't do a lot of things it is supposed to.

Comment: Welcome to the world of multiple browsers with no enforced standards